# Covering Space of Triangulable Space

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Assuming a triangulable space is one homeomorphic to a simplical complex.

How can one prove that any covering space of a triangulable space is triangulable?

I know that one can lift the homeomorphisms on each simplex to the covering space by using lift theorems and the fact that simplex are simply connected. But I can't seem to find a way to paste this "local" homeomorphisms into a global homeomorphisms or to describe the simplical complex associated to the covering space.

My question is motivated by the result relating euler characteristic of a covering space with the one of its base space.

Comment: I'm putting a bounty on this because I am stuck at the very same step. More precisely the following: the restriction of the covering map to the inverse image of a simplex is obviously $n$ copies of the said simplex. From this, how do we obtain a homeomorphism $|K|\to \tilde X$ where $\tilde X$ is the $n-$sheeted covering space and $|K|$ is a simplicial complex realized in $\mathbb R^k$?

Comment: @Y.Tamer: I suggest you re-read your comment. Several things do not really make sense and the last part is simply false: There are infinite-dimensional simplicial complexes. These do not embed (even topologically) in any ${\mathbb R}^k$. You seem to be assuming that $K$ is a finite simplicial complex, which is not a part of the OP and realizability has nothing to do with the OP.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan You are right, I seem to have confused the two different notions, which are i)The embedding of a simplicial complex into $\mathbb R^k$ and ii)The underlying topology of a simplicial complex. In my AT class we defined triangulability as "Being homeomorphic to some simplicial complex embedded in $\mathbb R^k$", which I now realize is not a common (Or, very meaningful) definition to make. Though intuitively, if $X$ is a space homeomorphic to a simplicial complex embedded in $\mathbb R^k$, then I would expect a *finite sheeted* covering space $\tilde X$ to have this same property.

Comment: @Y.Tamer: The definition of triangulability used in your class is **highly** nonstandard. Maybe you should edit your comments (especially the ones in the blue box) to clarify the issues.

Comment: @Y.Tamer: What I know is that every locally finite countable finite-dimensional simplicial complex admits a simplicial embedding in some $R^n$ (i.e. an embedding which is affine on each simplex).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you, can you provide a reference for this fact?

Comment: @Y.Tamer: The proof of existence of embedding of $k$-dimensional complex in $R^{2k+1}$ follows the lines of the Whitney embedding theorem for smooth manifolds (but is technically easier). I know how to do it (any any professional geometric topologist would know as well), but I am not sure about a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know about simplicial complexes but I can tell you (or just future visitors, considering the age of this post) about simplicial sets. Every simplicial complex is apparently the geometric realisation of a simplicial set, and simplicial sets are fundamental (apparently?) to algebraic topology, more so than these ‘complexes’.

In “Calculus of Fractions and Homotopy Theory”, the authors demonstrate to a good level of detail that, for any simplicial set $X$, the category of covering spaces of the space $|X|$ is equivalent to the category of simplicial coverings of $X$. In particular, there is a claim that for any covering map $p:Y\to|X|$, there is a simplicial set $K$ so that $Y\cong|K|$ over $|X|$ (they are isomorphic as covering spaces of $X$).

Specifically, if $\eta_X:X\to\mathsf{S}|X|$ is the adjunction unit, then $K$ is the pullback of $\mathsf{S}p:\mathsf{S}Y\to\mathsf{S}|X|$ along $\eta_X$. The map $K\to X$ is a simplicial covering that realises to a topological covering map $|K|\to|X|$, and the homeomorphism with $Y$ is taken by the composite $|K|\to|\mathsf{S}Y|\to Y$ where the latter map is the counit $\epsilon_Y$ and the former is the realisation of the pullback projection map. You check this composite is a homeomorphism by observing it places the fibres of every vertex of $X$ in $|K|,Y$ in bijection; noting covering maps surject on all connected components that they touch, and that this composite is a covering map since the base space $|X|$ is locally connected, you can deduce from bijecting the fibres for vertices that it is a one-sheeted cover i.e. a homeomorphism.

As an aside, for any locally path connected $Y$ admitting a simply connected covering space, we find the coverings of $Y$ are equivalent to the coverings of $\mathsf{S}Y$.

As another aside, [these notes](https://dmitripavlov.org/notes/topology.pdf) sketch an equivalence between the subgroups of the fundamental group of a connected simplicial set and coverings of that simplicial set. Taking realisations then gives you a nice “algorithm” for building, e.g., universal covers of ‘simplicial complexes’,’delta-sets’ and realisations of simplicial sets. It is enlightening to carry out this computation by hand for simple cases (e.g. the Möbius strip): it felt a little bit like magic, to be honest, the way everything automatically fits together in the correct way.

Comment: "In Calculus of Fractions and Homotopy Theory, the authors  ..." What does this mean?

Comment: @KritikerderElche It’s a book. I forget to use quote marks

Comment: @FShrike Perhaps you should mention the authors P. Gabriel  and M. Zisman.

Answer (score -1):

What you can always do if you are lazy (since you just care for "triangulable" and not for an induced or inherited simplicial structure), you can choose a barycentric subdivision so that neighborhods of the simplices lie entirely in one of (previously fixed) the trivializing open sets.

Comment: Every simplex is contained in a trivially covered open set, no?

Comment: I changed it so that neighborhoods should be contained (even though it is not needed). So that you directly obtain the pastings. Of course every simplex is simply covered. But the plan here is to fix an open trivializing cover (so that we have local homeomorphisms) and then start the barycentric subdivision.

Comment: Also, notice that if you start with a covering which has arbitrarily small open sets, you have to do this with certian care: it may well happen that there is no barycenteic subdivision of the initial triangulation all of whose simplices are contained in an open set of the covering.

Comment: Yes that is true I assumed a nice cover.